# How to add an element into list inside another list?

Tags: python, list

I need to add an element into a list which is inside another one
In my case i wanted to add 800 after 700

```
strange_list = [1, 2, [30, 40, [500, 600, 700], 80], 8]
strange_list.insert(2[2[2]], 800)
```

I tried something like this, but i'm getting an error

Comment: how would you access last element of the list in which you want to append. because if you can reach that element you can just append there

Answer (score 2):

The line `strange_list.insert(2[2[2]], 800)` is incorrect, because you cannot use this to specify where to insert the 800. Try this:

```py
strange_list = [1, 2, [30, 40, [500, 600, 700], 80], 8]
strange_list[2][2].insert(3, 800)
```

First, `strange_list[2][2]` access the list `[500, 600, 700]`. Next, `.insert(3, 800)` adds the number 800 as the 4th element of the list `[500, 600, 700]`, turning it into `[500, 600, 700, 800]`.

Answer (score 1):

Your access by index seems faulty. Try the following:

```py
strange_list[2][2].insert(3, 800)
```

I.e. access 3rd element of original list, then 3rd element of  `[30, 40, [500, 600, 700], 80]` which is `[500, 600, 700]` and insert at the 4th position.

Answer (score 1):

You can use insert: list.insert(pos, val)

Check this solution out:

```
strange_list[2][2].insert(3, 800)
```

Hope this helps!